# Present a UIViewController from SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I'm trying to present a UIViewController from a SKScene and I can't figure out how to do it. Most of what a Google search provides is how to present a share screen from a SKScene, but that is not what I'm trying to do. Just a regular View Controller that will have a button and a label (maybe a image as well).

Here's my code in my Intro.m. This is not the Gameplay scene, just a intro screen with a title,  play button and a remove ads button:

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "Intro.h"
#import "PurchasedViewController.h"

@interface PurchasedViewController ()

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

   if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

  .....

   SKSpriteNode *removeAds = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"removeAds"];
     removeAds.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)/6);
     removeAds.zPosition = 1;
     removeAds.name = @"RemoveAds";
    [self addChild:removeAds];
  }

 - (void)performTouches:(NSSet *)touches {    

  for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint pointInSKScene = [self.view convertPoint:[touch locationInView:self.view] toScene:self];
    SKNode *touchedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:pointInSKScene];

    if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"RemoveAds"]) {
        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"enter.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PurchasedViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
      }
    }
  }
```

The error Xcode gives me is "No visible @interface for Intro declares 'presentViewController: animated: completion'.

I'm a bit stumped because I haven't tried to present a UIViewController from a SKScene before and can't find a solution on the web.

Comment: Why did you name your `SKScene` as `PurchasedViewController`? :-)

Comment: The SKScene is actually called Intro.m. Purchased View Controller is the UIViewController I'm trying to present from the SKScene. I edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: Anyways, you cannot call `presentViewController:animated:completion:` from `SKScene`. Call it from `UIViewController`. You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to let view controller know, that the new view controller should be presented.

Comment: Referring to a SKScene as a View Controller further confuses the matter. A Sprite Kit class is not the same as a standard View Controller, which is what makes the task difficult for someone without experience doing it.It's not the same process as a segue from one View Controller to another in a standard iOS app.

Comment: See this question and my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578391/presenting-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that is much simpler than most of the solutions out there:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PurchasedVC"];
//Call on the RootViewController to present the New View Controller
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I also figured out an even simpler one liner if you create a segue in Storyboard and give it an identifier:

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PurchasedViewController" sender:self];
```