# return to collectionView from detail view

Tags: uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, modalviewcontroller

I have an app that I load a GameScene form a CollectionView.  I load the view just fine, but when I'm done I can't seem to be able to return to the collectionView.

I have tried

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
and 
[GameScene dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
and
[collectionViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but they all say  `No Visible @Interface` For `viewController` declares the selector `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`

Here is the code where I load the GameScene from the collectionView

```
-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    if (indexPath.row==0) {
         UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameSceneOne"];


    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    NSLog(@"mycell.image1.image:%@",myCell.image1.image);

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }}
```

Any Ideals of how to dismiss the gameScene and return to the CollectionView?

Comment: Explanation found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578391/presenting-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene

Comment: This was a very useful answer.  I had to change a few things around but I got everything working ok. Thanks