# Transition from SKScene to UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

For example if i have:

```
class SpriteKitScene: SKScene {
...
}
```

And in there i want to have an image, that when tapped(pressed, clicked, touched whatever)
loads another file with:

```
class UiViewcontrollerScene: UIViewcontroller {
...
}
```

I know how to transition from SKScene to SKScene, but i need to transition from SKScene to UIViewcontroller.

Comment: You have to grab the rootViewController. Then you can present normally from there. Anyways, when working with spritekit, you should stick to transitions if you don't have a real reason to do something like you are trying to achieve. Of course there are cases that you have to for example present something modally over a current view, but still this is SpriteKit. May I ask what is your  reason to do this ?

Comment: @Whirlwind I'm not sure how to 'grab' the rootViewController, and i am trying gamekit match making, so i want to transition from a sprite kit menu to searching matches, so far no luck.

Comment: Just search how to present view controller from within scene. I am not at computer so I can't write an appropiate answer. But you will figure it out probably . It is pretty simple.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21578391 It can give you some idea (read evey answer).So, delegation, notification, or grabbing a root view controller and presenting the new view could work.

Comment: @Whirlwind That is objective-c. I use swift.

Comment: Swift version of that code would be the same. Just translate it.

Comment: Scenes and view controllers are 2 different animals.  What you can do though, is have the scene tell the view that it wants to transition,  then have the view tell the viewcontroller to do all of the tranitioning

Answer (score 1):

First, set yourself up a delegate using a protocol for your view controller.

```
protocol UIViewControllerDelegate{
}
```

See here: https://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/ for a nice tutorial on how to do that

Create an SKView class that will be hosting this delegate

```
class GameView : SKView
{
       var delegate : UIViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

Then on your viewDidLoad in your UIViewController class,  assign the delegate to your view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    if let view = self.view as? GameView
    {
        view.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Now your view has a delegate to your view controller,  From this point, in your protocol file, make a method to transition

E.G.

```
protocol UIViewControllerDelegate
{
    optional  func transitionToMenuVC()
}
```

Then apply the code to your view controller class.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UIViewControllerDelegate
{
   ...
   func transitionToMenuVC()
   {
       // do transition code here
   }
}
```

Now you have it all set up for your view to communicate with your view controller.

In your Scene, you would just cast the scene's view to the GameView, and use the delegate to transition

```
class GameScene : SKScene
{
  ...
  func transition()
  { 

       if let view = self.view as? GameView
       {
           view.delegate.transitionToMenuVC()
       }
  }
}
```

Do note however, it is impossible to transition from scene to view controller, because they are 2 different animals.  You will be transitioning the views,  and are therefor stuck using the animations provided for views.

Comment: The   class GameView : SKView
                {
                    var delegate : UIViewControllerDelegate?
                } gives me an error : use of undeclared type 'UIViewControllerDelegate'

Comment: @Asphys what about it

Comment: You need to make that protocol, the tutorial calls it `FooTwoViewControllerDelegate`,  I called it UIViewControllerDelegate

Comment: @KnightOfDragon For some reason, it just doesn't transition. I may have done something wrong. Can you post a example project to somewhere like github?

Comment: @Asphys,  my code is only a template,  you need to actually fill in the transition code parts

Comment: I am not going to go through that effort.  If you want to create a temporary project doing everything I have explained into git hub,  I will look at it, but you need to test it first and make sure that you may have missed something, otherwise I won't help. (Basically do not create a template and copy and paste my code,  I want to see some efforts in recreating your problem)