# How to solve that SKTransition effect doesn't work during transiting?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

SKTransition doesn't work during transition from a scene to MainScene. It just jumps to MainScene without transition effect. You can find the codes below.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import TwitterKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import GoogleMobileAds

protocol SceneManagerDelegate {
    func presentMainScene()
    func presentGameScene()
    func presentWelcomeScene()
    func presentGameOverScene()
    func presentSettingsScene()
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController, TransitionDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate{
    /.....
}
/....
extension GameViewController: SceneManagerDelegate {            
    func presentSettingsScene() {
        let settingsScene = SettingsScene(fileNamed: "SettingsScene")
        settingsScene?.sceneManagerDelegate = self
        present(scene: settingsScene!)
    }

    func presentGameOverScene() {
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene")
        gameOverScene?.sceneManagerDelegate = self
        present(scene: gameOverScene!)
    }    

    func presentWelcomeScene() {
        let welcomeScene = WelcomeScene(fileNamed: "WelcomeScene")
        welcomeScene?.sceneManagerDelegate = self
        present(scene: welcomeScene!)
    }

    func presentMainScene() {
        let mainScene = MainScene(fileNamed: "MainScene")
        mainScene?.sceneManagerDelegate = self
        present(scene: mainScene!)
    }

    func presentGameScene() {
        let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
        gameScene?.sceneManagerDelegate = self
        present(scene: gameScene!)
    }

    func presentMatchingScene() {
        let matchingScene = MatchingScene(fileNamed: "MatchingScene")
        matchingScene?.sceneManagerDelegate = self
        present(scene: matchingScene!)
    }    

    func present(scene: SKScene) {
        let transition = SKTransition.reveal(with: .left, duration: 1)
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
                for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
                    view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
                }
            }

            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            scene.delegate = self as TransitionDelegate
            view.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
            view.showsFPS = true
        }
    }
}
```

To call the method from other scenes

```
var sceneManagerDelegate: SceneManagerDelegate? // sceneManagerDelegate.present....
```

Comment: your question is not clear. please elaborate it with giving SceneManagerDelegate protocol implementation

Comment: I just added other part of the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Your transition function is OK but your delegate implementation is faulty. In your **present(scene:)** method you  set ***scene.delegate = self as TransitionDelegate***, it would not be there. I have implemented your transition Code here [in **gameOver()** method in Swift 4](https://github.com/kayes55/SpritekitDelegateTestApp), and it works great. You can [see this tutorial for Delegate implementation for transition in SpriteKit](https://b4sht4.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/implementing-a-delegate-pattern-between-spritekit-scenes/). Also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310287/transition-from-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller?rq=1) given by KnightOfDragon.

Comment: Not sure if my answer solves any problems.  I am not seeing anything wrong with they way he is doing it.  Something else is causing errors, but I do not think the OP is explaining it correctly for us to understand what is truly going on.

Comment: I am not sure that the implementation is wrong. I guess there is something wrong with mainScene. But what?

Comment: As I rechecked, from scene to new scene, there is no problem. From the scene to previous one, there is a lag. My main scene is like a hub. All scenes returns to main scene. But I still dont know how to solve it.

Comment: I found the problem. It happens because of an animated node which is repeating forever. I just removed the animation. Everything is ok now. But I still need that animation. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: @TomB. I am going to need some more details,  What is the purpose of the animated node

Comment: It is just for show. self.headNode = self.childNode(withName: "//headNode") as? SKSpriteNode
        let spin = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi, duration: 20.0)
        let animate = SKAction.repeatForever(spin)
        headNode?.run(animate)